# How to disable PerfWatson in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, perfwatson

Half the time i open Visual Studio 11 I get the warning "Visual Studio PerfWatson has identified responsiveness problems...". Now I have already submitted once but I don't want to be bothered any more.

Can I turn off this "feature"?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable Perfwatson. It's an extension.

Comment: yep. I uninstalled the extension and it still gives me the dialog

Comment: Try unchecking Help > Perfwatson > Show prompt on upload.

Comment: Wont that cause it to upload automatically?

Comment: Maybe, although I'd say good luck to it if you've uninstalled it. :) I know you're a smart guy, but I have to ask... Did you restart VS and possibly Windows? Might not be completely dead yet.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2012 (v11) remove it by uninstalling, not disabling, extension in:

- Tools > Extensions and Updates

Comment: there is no perf watson in "Extensions and Updates" on my machine

Comment: @Simon: What's on your list?